# JAXRS: read an array of FormParams via POST web service

Tags: java, jax-rs, resteasy, ejb-3.2

I've an angular client that send me an array of object (sorting conditions):

```
sort[0][field]: modified
sort[0][dir]: asc
sort[1][field]: name
sort[1][dir]: desc
```

My web service interface is:

```
@POST
@Path("{pathcode}/grid")
@Produces(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Consumes(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED})
public GridResponse<FileObject> getFileList(
        @HeaderParam(value = "Authorization") String tokenAuth,
        @PathParam(value = "pathcode") String pathCode,
        @FormParam(value = "sort") List<SortingClause> sorts
        ) 
throws Exception;
```

I'm usign RESTEasy as jax-rs implementation.

How can i read an array of params if the param name is like "sort[i][k]"?

Why I cannot use a `MultivaluedHashMap<String,String>` as a parameter?

```
public GridResponse<FileObject> getListaFile(
        @HeaderParam(value = "Authorization") String tokenAuth,
        @PathParam(value = "pathcode") String pathCode,
        MultivaluedHashMap<String,String> formparam
        ) 
throws BssException;
```

Comment: What's the import for `MultivaluedHashMap`? Also what JAX-RS implementation are you using?

Comment: Thank you @vikarjramun for the comment. I edited the question. javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedHashMap not works but javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap does!

Comment: Why does the interface declare to consume a form urlencoded when you are showing an (unencoded) json media type?

Comment: @DanieleLicitra Is your question simply why `MultivaluedMap` doesn't work but `MultivaluedMap` does? If so, I think the issue is just with how RESTEasy implements it internally. RESTEasy likely has a `MessageBodyProvider<MultivaluedMap>` which is only invoked when the parameter is a `MultivaluedMap`. `MultivaluedHashMap` is likely meant to be used only in situations when you (or RESTEasy) need to instantiate a `MultivaluedMap` (such as in a unit test or when the framework actually constructs this object). Let me know if this answers your question.

Comment: Yes @vikarjramun , changing `Multivalued*Hash*Map` with `MultivaluedMap` solved my problem